# Triangulations of open sets in $\Bbb{ R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, triangulation

**Can every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be subdivided into a simplicial complex?**

Here, a simplicial complex $K$ must be a **locally finite** set of simplices in some $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that each face of a simplex in $K$ is also in $K$ and every non-empty intersection of simplices is in $K$.

I haven't been able to find any reference on this. I did see that the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be subdivided into such a simplicial complex in several different ways (for instance, see Triangulations
and Simplicial Methods by Chuangyin Dang). [The only other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536830/triangulating-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn) on this topic mentions [Whitney's covering Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_covering_lemma) as a way to subdivide open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ using dyadic cubes, but I am not sure how these generate a locally finite simplicial subdivision.

If the answer is yes, I would greatly appreciate a reference for it.

Comment: Why would using dyadic cubes not give a locally finite simplicial subdivision?  I haven't written out the details but it seems you should be able to triangulate the cubes one by one starting with the largest ones to get a locally finite triangulation.

Comment: One way to prove it is to use Delanay triangulation for a sufficiently fine discrete subset in your open set. Moreover, it is a general theorem due to Whitney, that every smooth manifold admits a triangulation.

Comment: Whitney's paper shows the existence of a homeomorphism from a simplicial complex onto a smooth manifold but does not guarantee being able to directly subdivide such a manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a simplicial complex, so it wouldn't work for what I need.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, what exactly guarantees that you can start subdividing each cube so that all intersections are faces of both simplexes? I do not have much background in this area so certain steps are not obvious. Thanks!